# Reupload, How do i convert a php file to python dictionary?

Tags: python, php, arrays, parsing, fpdf

After going over de fora, i did not find something that could solve this issue properly. I want to convert a file written in php to a python dictionary. In this case this file is a converted TrueType Font-file.

```
<?php
$type = 'TrueType';
$name = 'Calibri';
$desc = array('Ascent'=>750,'Descent'=>-250,'CapHeight'=>632,'Flags'=>32,'FontBBox'=>'[-503 -313 1240 1026]','ItalicAngle'=>0,'StemV'=>70,'MissingWidth'=>507);
$up = -113;
$ut = 65;
$cw = array(
    chr(0)=>507,chr(1)=>507,chr(2)=>507,chr(3)=>507,chr(4)=>507,chr(5)=>507,chr(6)=>507,chr(7)=>507,chr(8)=>507,chr(9)=>507,chr(10)=>507,chr(11)=>507,chr(12)=>507,chr(13)=>507,chr(14)=>507,chr(15)=>507,chr(16)=>507,chr(17)=>507,chr(18)=>507,chr(19)=>507,chr(20)=>507,chr(21)=>507,
    chr(22)=>507,chr(23)=>507,chr(24)=>507,chr(25)=>507,chr(26)=>507,chr(27)=>507,chr(28)=>507,chr(29)=>507,chr(30)=>507,chr(31)=>507,' '=>226,'!'=>326,'"'=>401,'#'=>498,'$'=>507,'%'=>715,'&'=>682,'\''=>221,'('=>303,')'=>303,'*'=>498,'+'=>498,
    ','=>250,'-'=>306,'.'=>252,'/'=>386,'0'=>507,'1'=>507,'2'=>507,'3'=>507,'4'=>507,'5'=>507,'6'=>507,'7'=>507,'8'=>507,'9'=>507,':'=>268,';'=>268,'<'=>498,'='=>498,'>'=>498,'?'=>463,'@'=>894,'A'=>579,
    'B'=>544,'C'=>533,'D'=>615,'E'=>488,'F'=>459,'G'=>631,'H'=>623,'I'=>252,'J'=>319,'K'=>520,'L'=>420,'M'=>855,'N'=>646,'O'=>662,'P'=>517,'Q'=>673,'R'=>543,'S'=>459,'T'=>487,'U'=>642,'V'=>567,'W'=>890,
    'X'=>519,'Y'=>487,'Z'=>468,'['=>307,'\\'=>386,']'=>307,'^'=>498,'_'=>498,'`'=>291,'a'=>479,'b'=>525,'c'=>423,'d'=>525,'e'=>498,'f'=>305,'g'=>471,'h'=>525,'i'=>229,'j'=>239,'k'=>455,'l'=>229,'m'=>799,
    'n'=>525,'o'=>527,'p'=>525,'q'=>525,'r'=>349,'s'=>391,'t'=>335,'u'=>525,'v'=>452,'w'=>715,'x'=>433,'y'=>453,'z'=>395,'{'=>314,'|'=>460,'}'=>314,'~'=>498,chr(127)=>507,chr(128)=>507,chr(129)=>507,chr(130)=>250,chr(131)=>305,
    chr(132)=>418,chr(133)=>690,chr(134)=>498,chr(135)=>498,chr(136)=>395,chr(137)=>1038,chr(138)=>459,chr(139)=>339,chr(140)=>867,chr(141)=>507,chr(142)=>468,chr(143)=>507,chr(144)=>507,chr(145)=>250,chr(146)=>250,chr(147)=>418,chr(148)=>418,chr(149)=>498,chr(150)=>498,chr(151)=>905,chr(152)=>450,chr(153)=>705,
    chr(154)=>391,chr(155)=>339,chr(156)=>850,chr(157)=>507,chr(158)=>395,chr(159)=>487,chr(160)=>226,chr(161)=>326,chr(162)=>498,chr(163)=>507,chr(164)=>498,chr(165)=>507,chr(166)=>498,chr(167)=>498,chr(168)=>393,chr(169)=>834,chr(170)=>402,chr(171)=>512,chr(172)=>498,chr(173)=>306,chr(174)=>507,chr(175)=>394,
    chr(176)=>339,chr(177)=>498,chr(178)=>336,chr(179)=>334,chr(180)=>292,chr(181)=>550,chr(182)=>586,chr(183)=>252,chr(184)=>307,chr(185)=>246,chr(186)=>422,chr(187)=>512,chr(188)=>636,chr(189)=>671,chr(190)=>675,chr(191)=>463,chr(192)=>579,chr(193)=>579,chr(194)=>579,chr(195)=>579,chr(196)=>579,chr(197)=>579,
    chr(198)=>763,chr(199)=>533,chr(200)=>488,chr(201)=>488,chr(202)=>488,chr(203)=>488,chr(204)=>252,chr(205)=>252,chr(206)=>252,chr(207)=>252,chr(208)=>625,chr(209)=>646,chr(210)=>662,chr(211)=>662,chr(212)=>662,chr(213)=>662,chr(214)=>662,chr(215)=>498,chr(216)=>664,chr(217)=>642,chr(218)=>642,chr(219)=>642,
    chr(220)=>642,chr(221)=>487,chr(222)=>517,chr(223)=>527,chr(224)=>479,chr(225)=>479,chr(226)=>479,chr(227)=>479,chr(228)=>479,chr(229)=>479,chr(230)=>773,chr(231)=>423,chr(232)=>498,chr(233)=>498,chr(234)=>498,chr(235)=>498,chr(236)=>229,chr(237)=>229,chr(238)=>229,chr(239)=>229,chr(240)=>525,chr(241)=>525,
    chr(242)=>527,chr(243)=>527,chr(244)=>527,chr(245)=>527,chr(246)=>527,chr(247)=>498,chr(248)=>529,chr(249)=>525,chr(250)=>525,chr(251)=>525,chr(252)=>525,chr(253)=>453,chr(254)=>525,chr(255)=>453);
$enc = 'cp1252';
$uv = array(0=>array(0,128),128=>8364,130=>8218,131=>402,132=>8222,133=>8230,134=>array(8224,2),136=>710,137=>8240,138=>352,139=>8249,140=>338,142=>381,145=>array(8216,2),147=>array(8220,2),149=>8226,150=>array(8211,2),152=>732,153=>8482,154=>353,155=>8250,156=>339,158=>382,159=>376,160=>array(160,96));
$file = 'calibri.z';
$originalsize = 77252;
$subsetted = true;
?>
```

to:

```
font = {"type":"TrueType",
        "name":"Calibri",
        "desc":{"Ascent":750,etc...},
        etc......
        }
```

I thank all in advance!

P.S. I reuploaded this question (my previous was closed) to share my solution in case someone else needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found was just writing the parsing myself:

```
import re
import regex

def parse_php(fontfile):
    font_dict = {}
    for item in php_chunks(fontfile):
        key, attr = item.split(" = ")
        attr = attr.replace("\t","").strip()
        attr = re.sub("^(.*);",r"\1",attr)
        # re.split("[,](?!'=>)",data["cw"])
        if re.match("'(.*)'",attr):
            attr = re.sub("'(.*)'",r"\1",attr)
        try:
            attr = eval(attr)
            font_dict[key.replace("$","").strip()] = attr
        except:            
            if "array" in attr:
                if re.match("^array\(",attr):
                    attr_dict = {}
                    attr = re.sub("array\((.*)\)",r"\1",attr)
                    attr = regex.split("(?<!array\(\d*)[,](?!'=>)",attr)
                    for row in attr:
                        dict_key, dict_item = row.strip().split("=>")
                        try:
                            attr_dict[str(eval(dict_key))] = eval(dict_item)
                        except:
                            attr_dict[str(eval(dict_key))] = dict_item
                    font_dict[key.replace("$","").strip()] = attr_dict
            else:
                font_dict[key.replace("$","").strip()] = attr
    return font_dict    
    
def php_chunks(raw):
    raw = raw.read()
    chunk = ""
    for idx, line in enumerate(raw.splitlines()):
        if line.startswith("$"):
            if idx != 1:
                yield chunk
            chunk = ""
            chunk = "".join(line)
        else:
            chunk = "".join([chunk,line])
```